# Is it possible to make the new row that is generated by onRowAdd material table to appear at the top of the section?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, material-table

Title.

As what is shown in the doc of material table, when you use editable with onRowAdd, the new row is always spawn at the bottom of the section. Is there a way to make that row appear at the top? Or how do I assign an onClick effect so that when user click on the Add button, it will automatically go to the bottom of the page? Let's just use the example on the doc:https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable

Comment: I don't know this library, but can't you just use `setData([newData, ...data])` instead of `setData([...data, newData])` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [option](https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props) called `addRowPoistion` to do exactly what you are looking for:

[image: add row position example]

In your table definition simply set the value to `"first"`.

```js
  <MaterialTable
        columns={tableColumns}
        data={data}
        title="Material Table - Add Row Position "
        options={{
          addRowPosition: "first",
          search: false,
          actionsColumnIndex: -1,
        }}
    ...
    />
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-editable-password-field-forked-ifq9w?file=/src/App.js) with a working example.